# Field values in node HTML body

Tags: nodes, 10

I am using Drupal 10 and trying to edit the body of a node. I want to use the node field values in the HTML body, for example *[field_name]*, but this does not appear to work as it only shows that specific text and not the actual value of the node. I also have tried *[field:field_name]* with no such luck. Is there any way to do this without having to edit any template file? I have the text format set to 'Full HTML'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use tokens. Drupal core has token functionality built in but doesn't include fields.

Have a look at this module it adds token support for fields https://drupal.org/project/token and this module https://drupal.org/project/token_filter allows you to use tokens in the text editor